# Address field appears blank in lightning-datable component

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, salesforcedx, lightning-datatable

It appears Price and Rent/Sales but the addresses appear blank, someone know how to solve this?

Controller

```
public with sharing class PropertyController {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<Property__c> getProperties(){
        return [SELECT Name , Address__City__s, Address__CountryCode__s, Address__Street__s,Address__PostalCode__s, Price__c,Sale_Rent__c FROM Property__c WHERE Status__c= 'Available' ORDER BY Price__c ASC];
    }
}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import NAME_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Property__c.Name';
import CITY_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Property__c.Address__City__s';
import COUNTRY_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Property__c.Address__CountryCode__s';
import STREET_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Property__c.Address__Street__s';
import POSTAL_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Property__c.Address__PostalCode__s';
import PRICE_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Property__c.Price__c';
import SALE_RENT_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Property__c.Sale_Rent__c';
import getProperties from '@salesforce/apex/PropertyController.getProperties';
const COLUMNS = [

    { label: 'Name', fieldName: NAME_FIELD.fieldApiName, type: 'text' },
    { label: 'City', fieldName: CITY_FIELD.fieldApiName, type: 'text' },
    { label: 'Country', fieldName: COUNTRY_FIELD.fieldApiName, type: 'text' },
    { label: 'Street', fieldName: STREET_FIELD.fieldApiName, type: 'text' },
    { label: 'Postal Code', fieldName: POSTAL_FIELD.fieldApiName, type: 'number' },
    { label: 'Price', fieldName: PRICE_FIELD.fieldApiName, type: 'currency' },
    { label: 'Sale/Rent', fieldName: SALE_RENT_FIELD.fieldApiName, type: 'picklist' },

];

export default class PropertyList extends LightningElement {
    columns = COLUMNS;
    @wire(getProperties)
    properties;
}
```

HTML

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Available Properties" icon-name="custom:custom85">
        <template if:true={properties.data}>
            <lightning-datatable
                key-field="Id"
                data={properties.data}
                columns={columns}>
           </lightning-datatable>
        </template>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

[image]